# UIImageView not aligning as expected in superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm doing a horizontally scrolling display of images and have a UIScrollView within a custom UIView. Scrollview is the same height as the custom view, but not as wide. I'm creating a UIImageView inside a for loop while setting up the images. Everything is working fine, except on loading, the UIImageView is displaying farther down the Y axis than it should be and I can't figure out why. Here's the code...

```
- (void)createImageViewer {

NSLog(@"Entered createImageViewer");
// size attributes of the main view and scroll view
CGFloat mainViewHeight = self.mainView.frame.size.height; // height of the main view
CGFloat mainViewWidth = self.mainView.frame.size.width; // width of the the main view
CGFloat scrollViewHeight = self.scrollView.frame.size.height; // height of the scroll view
CGFloat scrollViewWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width; // width of the scroll view

self.arrayOfImages = [self loadImages];
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

[self.mainView addSubview:self.scrollView];

for (int i = 0; i < [self.arrayOfImages count]; i++){
    UIImage *image = self.arrayOfImages[i];//Gets the image at the index i
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    //Shift each image over by the scrollView's width starting the first image at 0
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(scrollViewWidth * i, 0, scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight);

    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
}

int numberOfImages = [self.arrayOfImages count];

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * numberOfImages, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

}

I'm not allowed to post images, but basically, the image is positioned vertically about 50 points or so where I think it should, which would be even with the superview. I'm expecting this because the scrollview is created in storyboard and positioned evenly with the superview (identical height), but just not as wide. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you inside a UINavigationController? Check a property called "Adjust Scroll View Insets" on the Storyboard. Or check the whole inset topic for that matter. I'm not a big user of scrollViews but I sounds like that.

Comment: Which contentMode are you using?

Comment: contentMode is scale to fill. Played around with different content modes and it didn't fix the vertical alignment.

Comment: I can't find the "Adjust Scroll View Insets", but I did see content insets in storyboard inspector, but they're all set to 0 and adjusting them did absolutely nothing.

Comment: Could it be that the imageViews are positioned properly, but that the scrollView itself has a frame.origin.y greater than zero?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I created the scrollview in storyboard and aligned the height perfectly with the superview. And in the for loop where I'm initializing the UIImageViews where I call CGRectMake, I'm giving the y value a value of 0. Have played around a lot with that too, such as trying self.mainView.frame.origin.y, etc.

Comment: Also, I've done some NSLogging and I can see that the values look correct.

mainView x:0.000000 y:65.000000 (This is the superview)
scrollView x:29.000000 y:0.000000 (x is correct and y looks correct, but i know it's not)
imageView width: 320.000000, imageView height: 358.000000
scrollView width: 263.000000, scrollView height: 358.000000